# Crystal Reports 2011 report opening slowly

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that gets ran several hundred times from a C# program.  It is taking about 2 minutes to run each time it runs.  What I have discovered is that it runs in less than a second but it take a takes 2 minutes to open the report.  The report uses SQL Server 2008 and the report file is located on the local machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was the report had a printer embedded in it that was not defined on the machine the report was being run on.  Once the printer was removed the report ran faster.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps it will work for you

1) Firstly check your query how much it is taking at sql end as i presume that 2 mints a lot of time and we are also using crystal report they takes some time at first time but not 2 mints.

2) Secondly Crystal reports takes a time to load its DLLs at the first time you call a report. What SAP suggest is to load a dummy report at the first app excution using a thread or a background worker to get DLLs ready when calling your production reports.

Comment: then i will suggest that follow the second option.